# How can I get a component instance from within an event handler in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a dynamic component that I need to get a reference to in the event handler function. I can't use `ViewChild` because these components are dynamic and inside templates, etc.

```html
<example #e (click)="onExample(e)" />
```

When I do the above `e` is `undefined`. How can I get the reference to the component itself (not the element) from within the handler?

Comment: It seems like what I have here actually does work, I must have had some other issue in the more complex scenario that was messing this up but it does seem like just setting `#example` does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For projected content you can use ContentChild instead of ViewChild, maybe that fits your case - see docs: https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChild.

This is a good article on the topic: https://blog.mgechev.com/2016/01/23/angular2-viewchildren-contentchildren-difference-viewproviders/